# I am facing indentation issues when applying icon and text in my html list .How do I properly indent the items?

Tags: html, css

My html code:

```
<ul>
            <li><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"  ></i><a href="order.html">Orders</a></li>
            <li><i class='  fa fa-address-book'  aria-hidden="true" ></i> <a href="dashboard.html">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-cube" aria-hidden="true" ></i> <a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-gear" aria-hidden="true" ></i> <a href="SellerSection.html">Seller Section</a></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-dollar" aria-hidden="true"style ="font-size: 40px;" ></i> <a href="sales.html">Sales</a></li>
            <li><i class='fa fa-user' aria-hidden="true" ></i> <a href="customer.html">Customers</a></li>
            <li class="active"><i class='fa fa-user-circle' aria-hidden="true" ></i> <a href="admin.html">Admin</a></li>
            <li ><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left" aria-hidden="true"  ></i> <a href="return.html">Return</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Any help would be appeciated

Comment: which issue you have?

Comment: Through the wonderful world of Cascading Style Sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is simply to precise a fixed width for your icons `i` in your CSS.

Some quite important corrections:

- I removed the `font-size: 40px;` for the dollar sign, it was really bigger than others, I doubt it was on purpose
- There should be no spaces between the closing `</i>` and the opening of `<a ...`, or at least it should be the same number of spaces for each one (because they are displayed as spaces)

Some advices:

- I choose a width larger than the icon size so that there is a little horizontal space between the icons and the links
- You can control the vertical spacing with the icon's `height`. I choose 20 for a little more spacing
- You can control the icons size with `font-size` (because they are actually text characters) but i needs the `!important` because with the class `fa` it is set to `inherit` (do this only if you need another font size than the links, because with inherit it will follow the font size set on the `li`).  Adjust all those dimensions as you like
- To hide the discs that come with the list, just add `list-style: none;` to the `li`
- by default, a top and bottom margin are set on the `ul`, and a left padding, you can values to control them

```css
i {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 16px !important; 
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<ul>
            <li><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"  ></i><a href="order.html">Orders</a></li>
            <li><i class='  fa fa-address-book'  aria-hidden="true" ></i><a href="dashboard.html">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-cube" aria-hidden="true" ></i><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-gear" aria-hidden="true" ></i><a href="SellerSection.html">Seller Section</a></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-dollar" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="sales.html">Sales</a></li>
            <li><i class='fa fa-user' aria-hidden="true" ></i><a href="customer.html">Customers</a></li>
            <li class="active"><i class='fa fa-user-circle' aria-hidden="true" ></i><a href="admin.html">Admin</a></li>
            <li ><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left" aria-hidden="true"  ></i><a href="return.html">Return</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: actually I added dollar icon's size 40px on purpose because it had smaller size than others.But thanks for clearing the doubts

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Awesome List</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <style>
            .nav-list-item {
                margin-left:5px;
            }

            #active-nav-list-item{
                color:red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                <td><a class="nav-list-item" href="order.html">Orders</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><i class='  fa fa-address-book'  aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                <td><a class="nav-list-item" href="dashboard.html">Dashboard</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><i class="fa fa-cube" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                <td><a class="nav-list-item" href="products.html">Products</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><i class="fa fa-gear" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                <td><a class="nav-list-item" href="SellerSection.html">Seller Section</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><i class="fa fa-dollar" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                <td><a class="nav-list-item" href="sales.html">Sales</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><i class='fa fa-user' aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                <td><a class="nav-list-item" href="customer.html">Customers</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><i class='fa fa-user-circle' id="active-nav-list-item" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                <td><a class="nav-list-item" id="active-nav-list-item" href="admin.html">Admin</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                <td><a class="nav-list-item" href="return.html">Return</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here I used `<table>` and its related tags to keep items in proper indentation using html tables. Also added a CSS class `.nav-list-item` to indent list items a bit away from their respective icons. Finally, I added an CSS id `#active-nav-list-item` to highlight the active item.

Comment: Please help me in getting the output given in image link

Comment: I wonder why you using unordered list, because it places a DOT bullet before each icon. Aren't we supposed to use those icons as our unordered list's bullet?

Comment: @gpl it's actually much more correct semantically to use html lists for.. hum, lists. Tables should be reserved to tabular data and are very dicouraged for presentation "tricks" since years now. You can easily disable the dots with css, and tables will come with its own flaws

Comment: To extend on my previous comment, the reason tons of websites use ul/li for their menus (what the OP is apparently doing) is that it can easily switch to vertical or horizontal display with CSS, to adapt to mobile/desktop or responsive design. Much harder with tables, if possible at all. I recommend you take a look at the menu of this very site to verify (both top right horizontal menu and the dropdown content are made like this)